# RequestBuilder bodyMultipart() method has issue?

Tags: java, playframework

I am using play 2.5.3, but I also tried 2.5.4 and 2.5.12 and all have the same issue.

I want to do a unit test of my controller with multipart form body in the request. Here's my code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import controllers.payment.application.PaymentApplicationController;
import facade.PaymentApplicationFacade;
import it.innove.play.pdf.PdfGenerator;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import play.Application;
import play.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder;
import play.libs.Json;
import play.mvc.Http.MultipartFormData;
import play.mvc.Http.RequestBuilder;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.test.WithApplication;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static play.mvc.Http.Status.OK;
import static play.test.Helpers.*;

@Test
public void testSubmit() {

    MultipartFormData.DataPart dp = new MultipartFormData.DataPart("FirstName", "test");

    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = fakeRequest().bodyMultipart(Arrays.asList(dp), mat);

    Result result = invokeWithContext(requestBuilder, ()->new PaymentApplicationController(paymentApplicationFacade, pdfGenerator).submit());
    assertEquals(OK, result.status());
    assertEquals("text/html", result.contentType().get());
    assertEquals("utf-8", result.charset().get());
    assertTrue(contentAsString(result).contains("Welcome"));
}
```

Seems the `bodyMultipart()` method always create a request with body of `RawBuffer` type. I checked the `RequestBuilder` code:

```
public RequestBuilder bodyMultipart(List<MultipartFormData.Part<Source<ByteString, ?>>> data, Materializer mat) {
    String boundary = MultipartFormatter.randomBoundary();
    try {
        ByteString materializedData = MultipartFormatter
                .transform(Source.from(data), boundary)
                .runWith(Sink.reduce(ByteString::concat), mat)
                .toCompletableFuture()
                .get();

        play.api.mvc.RawBuffer buffer = new play.api.mvc.RawBuffer(materializedData.size(), materializedData);
        return body(new RequestBody(JavaParsers.toJavaRaw(buffer)), MultipartFormatter.boundaryToContentType(boundary));
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failure while materializing Multipart/Form Data");
    }
}
```

It looks like it really does this. This results in when my controller does:

```
MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
```

It just return `null`.

Anybody can help on this?

Comment: could you build it as `RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder().bodyForm(ImmutableMap.of("FirstName", "test"));` ?

Comment: Tried that. But the controller I test contains:  MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();

This will return null if there's only form in the request.

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily bypass this by using my wrapper for RequestBuilder and MultipartFormData, but still need an elegant solution.

In test:

```
RequestBuilder requestBuilder = fakeRequest();

MyRequestBuilder myRequestBuilder = new MyRequestBuilder(requestBuilder);
myRequestBuilder.setBody(new Http.RequestBody(myMultipartFormData), "multipart/form-data");

Result result = invokeWithContext(myRequestBuilder, ()->new PaymentApplicationController(paymentApplicationFacade, pdfGenerator).submit());
```

MyRequestBuilder class:

```
import play.mvc.Http.RequestBody;
import play.mvc.Http.RequestBuilder;

/**
 * Created by yongmu on 3/2/17.
 */
public class MyRequestBuilder extends RequestBuilder {
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder;

    public MyRequestBuilder(RequestBuilder requestBuilder) {
        this.requestBuilder = requestBuilder;
    }

    public void setBody(RequestBody body, String contentType) {
        super.body(body, contentType);
    }
}
```

MyMultipartFormData class:

```
import play.mvc.Http.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by yongmu on 3/2/17.
 */
public class MyMultipartFormData<A> extends MultipartFormData<A> {
    Map<String, String> form;

    public MyMultipartFormData(Map<String, String> form) {
        this.form = form;
    }

    public Map<String, String[]> asFormUrlEncoded() {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves all file parts.
     *
     * @return the file parts
     */
    public List<FilePart<A>> getFiles() {
        return null;
    }
}
```